# Flutter Null Safety and Firebase authentication error

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, dart-null-safety

I am using flutter and firebase for my app. I don't know why I am getting error in below code. With degrade version of flutter(Without null safety) it is working fine but after migrating over null safety, I am facing problem here.

```
class AuthenticationService {

  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  users.User? _userFromFirebase(User user){
    return user != null ? users.User(id: user.uid, email: user.email):null;
  }

  User? user() {
    firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if(user == null){
        return null;
      } else {
        return user; //I am getting error here in return statement
      }
    });
  }
  Future loginWithEmail({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  Future register({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

}
```

In `User? user(){}` method, I am getting error in return statement. Can anyone have idea about it??

I think some small mistake is there which I am not able to identifying it.

The error is :

```
Error: Can't return a value from a void function.
```

Comment: "I am getting error in return statement" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace that you get.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : I have edited the question with exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return something from within the `listen` callback to the scope of your `user()` function.

The closest equivalent to what you have now is to return a `Future<User?>` with something like this:

```
Future<User?> user() {
  return firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().first()
}
```

You have to return a `Future` here (or mark the function as `async`, which does pretty much the same thing) because the `authStateChanges()` comes from Firebase asynchronously, and won't yet be available by the time the `return` statement runs.

I recommend reading up on asynchronous behavior in Flutter/Dart, for example with:

- [Video: Async/Await - Flutter in Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY)
- [Codelab: Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: Thanks for the direction.... it really helps me...

Answer (score 0):

if it is a callback and it has to wait for some time then you have to declare your method as future. because the return type of user is future which takes some time so you have to make the method as future...

hope this works for you